# Implementing Firebase Account Settings In OverFlow Menu

Tags: android, android-layout, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Firebase and development things, I've made an app using Firebase and given it a method of signing in and out but in an activity, I want the logout and other account settings to be done by OverFlow menu if possible.

Code Of Activity which I want to implement on OverFlow menu:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth; 
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btnChangeEmail, btnChangePassword, btnSendResetEmail,    btnRemoveUser,
        changeEmail, changePassword, sendEmail, remove, signOut;

private EditText oldEmail, newEmail, password, newPassword;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener;
private FirebaseAuth auth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //get firebase auth instance
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //get current user
    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user == null) {
                // user auth state is changed - user is null
                // launch login activity
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    };

    btnChangeEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.change_email_button);
    btnChangePassword = (Button) findViewById(R.id.change_password_button);
    btnSendResetEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sending_pass_reset_button);
    btnRemoveUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.remove_user_button);
    changeEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changeEmail);
    changePassword = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changePass);
    sendEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    remove = (Button) findViewById(R.id.remove);
    signOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_out);

    oldEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.old_email);
    newEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_email);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    newPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newPassword);

    oldEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    newEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    password.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    newPassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    changeEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    changePassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    sendEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    remove.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    if (progressBar != null) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    btnChangeEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            oldEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            newEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            password.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            newPassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            changeEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            changePassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            sendEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            remove.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    changeEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (user != null && !newEmail.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                user.updateEmail(newEmail.getText().toString().trim())
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Email address is updated. Please sign in with new email id!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    signOut();
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to update email!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            }
                        });
            } else if (newEmail.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                newEmail.setError("Enter email");
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });

    btnChangePassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            oldEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            newEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            password.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            newPassword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            changeEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            changePassword.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            sendEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            remove.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    changePassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (user != null && !newPassword.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                if (newPassword.getText().toString().trim().length() < 6) {
                    newPassword.setError("Password too short, enter minimum 6 characters");
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    user.updatePassword(newPassword.getText().toString().trim())
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Password is updated, sign in with new password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        signOut();
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to update password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            } else if (newPassword.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                newPassword.setError("Enter password");
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });

    btnSendResetEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            oldEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            newEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            password.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            newPassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            changeEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            changePassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            sendEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            remove.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    sendEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (!oldEmail.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(oldEmail.getText().toString().trim())
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Reset password email is sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to send reset email!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            }
                        });
            } else {
                oldEmail.setError("Enter email");
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });

    btnRemoveUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (user != null) {
                user.delete()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your profile is deleted:( Create a account now!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignupActivity.class));
                                    finish();
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to delete your account!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    });

    signOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signOut();
        }
    });

}

//sign out method
public void signOut() {
    auth.signOut();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    auth.addAuthStateListener(authListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (authListener != null) {
        auth.removeAuthStateListener(authListener);
    }
}
}
```

Image:

[!Check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5OsS.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5OsS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to force your icon into the overflow, you must add `app:showAsAction="never"` to your `<item>` tag in your menu xml file. E.g:

```
<item
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title=""
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    />
```

If you don't even have the menu actions, follow these  steps:

**Step 1: Create the menu xml** Right click on your `res` directory, select New>Android Resource Directory. Set the resource name to menu and add to it a name. Now, create a menu.xml if it hasn't been created automatically, and add all the items you need. For example, for a log out button in the Overflow menu:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:title="@string/logout"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:id="@+id/logout"

    />
</menu>
```

The `showAsIcon` attribute set as `never' makes it always show in the overflow.

**Step 2: Inflate and give actions**: Override onCreateOptions menu so you can create your menus:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    //Inflate the menu.xml you created:
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_cno, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**Step 3:** Set the callbacks:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        //The id of the <item> tag we created was logout, so, if the user clicks on an item with the id logout, we call on doWhateverYouWant(), in your case, doWhateverYouWant() is you logout method.
        case R.id.logout:
            doWhateverYouWant();
            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return false;

}
```

You're done.

Comment: Thanks! I've reached to somewhere :) but still what i made was a button click event of signing out i want it to be a menu click event, like if i click logout it should log me out from the overflow menu itself, where as logout in this is just a case of onOptionsSelection.

Comment: When you added a `menu.xml` and inflated it in `onCreateOptionsMenu`, it should have added the icons to your actionbar/toolbar. Then, in `onOptionsItemSelected`, instead of `doWhateverYouWant`, put your logout stuff.

Comment: If you want something else, then please be more clear.